# Android JSON parsing issue

Tags: android, json, parsing

i have a json file with bunch of items diferent categories , and i want to check categorie and if does match with given condition i want to be displayed in listview , this is what i've came up .. but it doent work , listview is empty

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            JinnerObject = Jobject.getJSONObject("data");
            Jarray = JinnerObject.getJSONArray("events");
            for(int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++){
                JeventObject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String  _EV_OP1         = JeventObject.getString(EV_OP1);
                String  _EV_OP2         = JeventObject.getString(EV_OP2);
                String  _EV_COEF1       = JeventObject.getString(EV_COEF1);
                String  _EV_COEF2       = JeventObject.getString(EV_COEF2);
                String  _EV_STIME       = JeventObject.getString(EV_STIME);
                String  _EV_HOST        = JeventObject.getString(EV_HOST);
                String  _EV_DESC        = JeventObject.getString(EV_DESC);
                String  _EV_TIP         = JeventObject.getString(EV_TIP);
                String  _EV_CAT         = JeventObject.getString(EV_CAT);

                    if(_EV_CAT == C){
                    HashMap<String, String> Events_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Events_map.put(EV_OP1,      _EV_OP1);
                    Events_map.put(EV_OP2,      _EV_OP2);
                    Events_map.put(EV_COEF1,    _EV_COEF1);
                    Events_map.put(EV_COEF2,    _EV_COEF2);
                    Events_map.put(EV_STIME,    _EV_STIME);
                    Events_map.put(EV_HOST,     _EV_HOST);
                    Events_map.put(EV_DESC,     _EV_DESC);
                    Events_map.put(EV_TIP,      _EV_TIP);

                    eventsList.add(Events_map);
                    }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
if(_EV_CAT == C)
```

to

```
if(_EV_CAT.equalsIgnoreCase(C))
```

for comparing Strings always use `equalsIgnoreCase` or `equals` because `==` operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance